# arp "who-has tell" on cloned machine

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, arp

I have a urgent problem to solve today, but I'm lost. Please help.

I've cloned a Virtual Machine hosted on VM Ware ESXi 4.1
The OS is now Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, but at the time of cloning it was 10.04 LTS.

I fixed the MAC address manually inside `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. It is a known problem on Ubuntu. I had to remove the old MAC address and set the new one as eth0.

Everything seems to work fine, except ARP.
My provider OVH sent me a warning to resolve it today (this is the second day) or they will block my IP!

The log contains many lines like this:

```
Tue Jun 5 01:04:29 2012 : arp who-has 178.32.136.212 tell 178.32.136.224
```

where .224 is the cloned server that is causing problems, and .212 is the cloned one.

`arp -na` returns:

```
? (178.33.230.254) at 00:07:b4:00:00:02 [ether] on eth0
? (178.32.136.212) at 00:50:56:09:8e:f1 [ether] on eth0
```

The first IP is the ESXi machine.
The second one should not be there.

I'm not an expert and I don't know what else to do to fix this problem.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

ifcofig on .224:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:01:32:c6
      inet addr:178.32.136.224  Bcast:178.32.136.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe01:32c6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:399924 errors:0 dropped:465 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:241884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:58006071 (58.0 MB)  TX bytes:663603166 (663.6 MB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:516216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:516216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:236284275 (236.2 MB)  TX bytes:236284275 (236.2 MB)
```

ifconfig on .212:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:09:8e:f1
      inet addr:178.32.136.212  Bcast:178.32.136.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe09:8ef1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:15134444 (15.1 MB)  TX bytes:2683025 (2.6 MB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:9944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:1139347 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1139347 (1.1 MB)
```

I've executed `arp -vd 178.32.136.212` to delete the entry in the arp. But after about one our it is listed again.
During the time that the entry was deleted the log was clear.
Why it came back?

Comment: can you show `ifconfig` output from both servers?

Comment: added ifconfig.

Comment: I have executed `arp -d 178.32.136.212`
Now the entry is no more listed, but I have fear that it could come back

Comment: ARP works fine, as I can see. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: How did you test it? It could be very useful to know that.
Probably it is working correctly because I just deleted the entries?
The problem is just that the provider is complaining about a "huge amount of useless traffic" from my IP. this was last entry in the log:
`Tue Jun 5 12:04:56 2012 : arp who-has 178.32.136.212 tell 178.32.136.224`

Comment: you have correct MAC and IP in arp table. It means ARP is working fine.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ARP who-has" is a broadcast packet. It is normal for you to receive it, since both of your server's interfaces are in one broadcast domain.

It is possible that your provider expects you to have all virtual servers in routed mode, but you use bridged. In this case broadcast packet is not limited to your virtual interfaces, and floods your physical uplink.

Comment: The provider specs indicates to set the broadcast to the same ip of the virtual machine. Yesterday a system administrator told me that is wrong and that should be .255
Anyway the ARP problem was the same before and after the change.
Do you think that the provider specs are fine. Should I set the broadcast to the same IP of the server?

Comment: broadcast IP is somewhat different. ARP is using ethernet broadcast, not IP. If you are using IP broadcast... well, if you do, you'd have known about that.

Comment: I'm sure that they want them in bridge mode. This is the link they told me to look at to resolve the problem:
http://help.ovh.co.uk/BridgeClient
The problem is that I can't set the mask to 255.255.255.255. The network doesn't start.

Comment: It's a nice and detailed guide. Did you follow it? You may miss the 'assign a mac to a virtual IP FailOver' part. Netmask and broadcast you are using for virtual servers is wrong.

Comment: I set broadcast as they want (the same as Failove IP), but I can't assign netmask to 255.255.255.255 and gateway to the .254 of the physical host. When I try I get 'Failed to bring up eth0'. I've seen that arp cache has nothing to do with this. Sorry for that.

Comment: Ok I fixed it in the interfaces settings. I was setting gateway two time.s the first one with `post-up route add default gw 178.33.230.254`, the second one with `gateway 178.33.230.254`. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll flag your answer as accepted because I didn't ask the problem correctly and you answers was focused on what I told.

Answer (score -4):

Why not just get two Ubuntu VPS's from your ISP? They shouldn't cost much and the networking and virtualization intricacies would be their problem, not yours...